# Dependency injection with Niject and MVC and WCF and N- tier artichecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, dependency-injection, ninject

I have started a project in VS 2012; my solution has the following structure.

1) Web Interface (MVC 4) calling WCF layer

2) WCF layer is calling Business Logic Layer

3) Business Logic Layer is calling Repository Layer (generic repository)

4) Repository is call Data Access Layer (DAL = EF 5.0)

Question:

I want to use Ninject (ver 3) for DI

1) Do i need to add Ninject in each of my layer/project level to resolve the DI ?

In which layer should i add the following code to create the bindings. As the following code goes into the NinjectWebCommon.cs class for binding.

```
// 'real' implementations or (Bindings)

kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>();
kernel.Bind<IAuthorBLL>().To<AuthorBLL>();
```

2) Do i need to add Ninject in each project/layer of my solution and define the bindings in each NinjectWebCommon.cs class.

Or the binging should only be defined in the WCF layer but then i will need to add the referance of each of my projects in WCF project.

Or the binging should only be defined in the start of MVC layer but then i will need to add the referance of each of my projects in my MVC project.

please advice. Many thanks.

If you can point me to any sample working code with all the above layers and Ninject that would be great. I tried but cannot find any thing like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of depencency injection is that every class that is constructed pronounces it's dependencies in the constructor(usually).
 The final layer will act as an orchestra leader and will choose which dependencies to use. To do this that layer needs to have dependencies on all underlying layers(how else to point to the trumpets to play part x, or to entity framework repositories for data handling).
In your case however you have 2 applications(which i'm never a big fan of but i see more and more people doing it )
An mvc website and a wcf service.
Both of these applications will have to play orchestra leader for their orchestra.
Your mvc website application will setup ninject to create your wcf service components.
The wcf service application will setup ninject to create a specific set of logic and repository classes.
It will work but i would look into scratching the wcf layer in between all together.
Usually your mvc website will be the only consumer and what's the point of a wcf service then?
 If you have more consumers then ignore that remark and set it up with 2 ninjects.

Comment: Hi Kristof, thanks for your reply, yes i have more consumers a mobile view site which will be accessing WCF layer too. I will try your suggestions in my solution now and will update you if its working. Many Thanks for your time.

Comment: Good luck , be sure to check out ninject auto registration btw !